# How to stop a running script using another script that's running in a different console?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

My aim is to halve the time to find the answer but if a script finds the answer then I want it to stop the other running script as well but I don't know how to do this and have been searching for ages... :'(

Here is some context:
I am trying to find a particular triangular number which has over 1000 divisors and would like to run a script that checks incrementally odd triangular numbers and run another script that checks the even cases, effectively dual processing my way to get the answer!

Thank you in advance!

An example of a desired outcome:

script_evens has found the answer.

script_evens executes command that stops script_odds.

Comment: What starts these processes running? Whatever process starts them should be responsible for terminating them.

Comment: You should consider multithreading. You can also launch multiple threads (depending on the number of cores you have)...

Comment: If this is python, even multithreading will not help because of the GIL (Global Interpreter Lock) which only allows one thread to run at a time thus rendering multiple threads running python code, useless. You will need to resort to multiprocessing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you're trying to reinvent the wheel of multithreading. What you really want is a single process that spawns multiple processes, and then kills them when one of them finds an answer. Multithreading/multiprocessing can be complicated and is probably beyond the scope of this answer, but here's a short starter tutorial in python: https://blog.usejournal.com/multithreading-vs-multiprocessing-in-python-c7dc88b50b5b

Comment: Thanks mate, I am pretty new to Python so your help means a lot!